# Subscript out of range error on array

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to read a list of ids (integers) into a one dimensional array in an excel macro.

I have counted the number of IDs that will need to be inputted in a previous step therefore know what my array size needs to be. Now I want to create an array and read the values into that array. Below is the code that is giving me a "runtime error 9, subscript out of range" message on the line where I am reading the "RowID" into the array.  Please let me know what I am doing incorrectly.

Notes:
PD_incD is the count of ids to be read into array.

```
Dim AIN As Integer 'Array index
Dim PD_IncD_Array() As Variant
ReDim PD_IncD_Array(1 To PD_IncD) As Variant 'Create array for recording section IDs

AIN = 1 'Reset value
RowID = PD_1stRow 'Reset first row to begin search

Do While Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Piping Data").Cells(RowID, 3).Value)
    If Worksheets("Piping Data").Cells(RowID, 3).Value = 1 Then
        PD_IncD_Array(AIN, 1) = RowID
        AIN = AIN + 1
    Else
        RowID = RowID + 1
    End If
Loop

MsgBox (PD_IncD_Array(AIN, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is correct but the cause is related to your logic.

You never increment `RowID` if the first part of your if statement is true.  This leaves you with an infinite loop but since you're assigning a value to an array you get an out of bounds error first.

I'm not sure your exact logic but I'm guessing you want to increment the `RowID` every loop like this:

```
Do While Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Piping Data").Cells(RowID, 3).Value)
    If Worksheets("Piping Data").Cells(RowID, 3).Value = 1 Then
       ' ReDim Preserve PD_IncD_Array(UBound(PD_IncD_Array) + 1)
        PD_IncD_Array(AIN, 1) = RowID
        AIN = AIN + 1
    End If

    RowID = RowID + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the array as though it had 2 dimensions when you use (x, y) syntax. You only have an array with 1 dimension so you will get that error. Just remove the ", 1" - it has no purpose here.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to assign `PD_IncD_Array`, for `AIN` between `1` and `PD_IncD`. You are likely not satisfying this condition.

Check the values of `PD_IncD`, and `AIN` at error (you may use `MsgBox` or debug). Also clarify the line throwing the error.